# object, variable, and symbols in R

Tags: r, symbols

I'm confused regarding the definition of `[symbol]`[1](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/name.html). In the following example, my understanding is that `h` is a variable and an object, `hs` is the name or symbol of `h`, but why `hs` is '`12`' and not `h`?

```
h=12
is.symbol(h) # FALSE
hs=as.symbol(h)
is.symbol(hs) # TRUE
hs # `12`
eval(hs) # Error in eval(hs) : object '12' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because `as.name` (identical to `as.symbol`) converts the value stored in `h` to a symbol, it doesn't act on the name `h` itself. (Which is already a name, so why are we coercing to a name...?)

I think you're looking for something closer to the functionality of `substitute()`:

```
h <- 12

# Converts the value stored in h to a symbol
hs1 <- as.name(h)
str(hs1) # symbol 12

eval(hs1) # Error in eval(hs1) : object '12' not found

hs2 <- substitute(h)
str(hs2) # symbol h

eval(hs2) # 12
```

Comment: Thank you! if `h` is already a name, why `is.name(h)` is `FALSE`?

Comment: @blueskyddd This gets semantically confusing, and it's easy to use language casually in ways that can mislead, like I might have done in my answer. `h` as we write it back and forth to each other might refer to either (1) the variable holding the value 12, or (2) than symbol that R uses to refer to that variable. As you discovered, in almost all cases when we type `h` R will interpret that as you meaning the variable, not the symbol. To tell R you mean the symbol you have to use special tools, like `substitute`. So `is.name(h)` is FALSE because R thinks you're asking about the variable.

Comment: @blueskyddd It's as though R's default reading of `chair` is to automatically substitute the physical object in its place. If you want R to think about the _word_ `chair` you have to give it nudge, via something like `substitute()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, @joran! The definition of symbol from the above URL is `A ‘name’ (also known as a ‘symbol’) is a way to refer to R objects by name (rather than the value of the object, if any, bound to that name).` So `h` is a variable and also an object, and its value is `12`. `12` itself is not an object, is my understanding correct?

Comment: I want to understand the concept of object and symbol because of my attempt to write functions with parameters that can be either variables (e.g. string) or data masking in tidyverse, e.g. say data.frame `df` contains a column named `"b"`, then is the `b` in `mutate(df, a=b+2)` an object or a symbol of an object named `b`?